# placing ci and wp in server root directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I will like to know if it is possible to places ci and wp in the same root directory and then load each index.php using some conditions in .htaccess file.

For example, I want that whenever the domain is access (i.e www.domain.org), ci index should be used. And when a subdirectory like www.domain.org/blog, wp index should be used.

Comment: What makes you want to do it like this? I think you want to wp index living in the /blog directory and the CI index in the root.

Comment: /blog is not a directory but a page in wp

Comment: codeigniter will be use to load static pages like about, homepage, etc while wp will handle the blog part, why I don't want to place wp in a subdir is because of SEO. am performing an upgrade to an existing site

Comment: hi, if you want to use ci USE IT, but if you want to make some differences just use the `application/config/route.php` for all your ci routes and make the **php or html** file with that name

Comment: you can make folder blog and put your wordpress in that and now you can access your wordpress